# Assign Custom Domain A Record to Traffic Manager DNS Name

Tags: azure, service, cloud, traffic, azure-traffic-manager

I have two Cloud Services

**service1.cloudapp.net**

**service2.cloudapp.net**

each cloud service is having 1 VM with their own Public IP

each VM is running a website.

**VM1 IP is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**

**VM2 IP is zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz**

Now i have created a Round Robin Traffic Manager (xyzrobin.trafficmanager.net) to which I have assigned two end points pointing to each of the cloud services (service1 and service2).

Now i want to assign my Domain name xyz.com to the traffic manager **xyzrobin.trafficmanager.net** but the DNS manager is not allowing me to add and is asking for an IP address for the A record.

After studying online a lot I created one CNAME record www for xyz.com and assigned the xyzrobin.trafficmanager.net to it

**CNAME** ---- **www** ---- **xyzrobin.trafficmanager.net**

also another record as this

**A** ---- **xyz.com** ---- **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx** (VM1 IP)

now if i type in browser xyz.com i am taken to VM1 and when i type www.xyz.com i am taken to best selection among VM1 and VM2 via traffic manager.

How do i set the xyz.com to go through the traffic manager.

please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> When your website is configured as a Traffic Manager endpoint, you
>   will use the .trafficmanager.net address when creating DNS records.
>
> You can only use CNAME records with Traffic Manager

Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-traffic-manager-custom-domain-name/

Comment: how to point the TLD to the traffic manager endpoint? any walk through or trick to do so or is there any proper way to achieve that?

Comment: Most registrars don't let you point a TLD to a CNAME, only A records. As an alternative, you can have another site that redirects (HTTP 301) from the TLD to the www.* site that is pointing to your traffic manager.

Comment: this sucks. Lets me real. I have to use a DNS resolver, to point naked domains, to their CNAME record.